# The Portion of the Earth's Biomass Attributable to Ants

Tags: entomology, bioinformatics, ant

An exterminator came to the house today (bad ant problem).

He claimed that 20% of the earth's biomass is comprised of ants.

I was surprised by this statement.

I figured that I would post the question here (hope that's OK) and ask if someone can, generally speaking, either confirm this assertion or refute it.

If the exterminator's statement is false, what would be a more accurate estimate? If you can provide a reason or two, I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: I've suggested this question as a duplicate of the one linked above because, even though it doesn't specifically refer to ants, the graph in the answer shows that arthropods (which includes ants) are a measly 1 gigatons, compared to the 450 gigatons of plants. If you dig into the supplemental information, you find that terrestrial arthropods are less than 0.2 gigatons, and a lot of that isn't ants (e.g., 0.07 Gt termites), so ants are way under 20% even just of animals.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incorrect statement. According to an answer to a question in a different SE, https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/is-the-total-biomass-of-ants-roughly-equal-to-the-total-biomass-of-humans, ants comprise roughly 15-20% of the (terrestrial animals), which is only a small percentage of the *total biomass* that includes sea life and plant life, among other forms of biomass, on earth.

Comment: If you read the sources for that Skeptics post carefully, they claim “On average, ants monopolize 15–20% of the **terrestrial animal** biomass…”. So, that excludes all aquatic life and non-animal terrestrial life, including plants. So I’d say the 20% figure given by OP is likely off by orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Alex K Thank you for providing the link to the Sekptics posting. It is helpful.

Comment: @acvill I said "total dry biomass" to mean terrestrial animals, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @AlexK in a biological context, "dry biomass" typically refers to dehydrated mass (that is to say, organic material minus water weight). Also, there is nothing about the phrase "dry biomass" that suggests it refers to animal biomass exclusively. Your answer could be a good one if you correct the language to accurately reflect your linked source, and rewrite your conclusion ("This is a possibly true statement") to reflect the fact that terrestrial animal biomass is a small fraction of earth's total biomass.